# Swagger of List<Object> Types Example

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have response which contains `List<Image>` images which is as following.

```
  {
         images: [
          {
            "name": "ABC",
             "content": "This is text"
          },
          {
          "name": "ABC",
          "content": "This is text"
        }
       ]
  }
```

The `YAML` file is similar like the following example. Is the following `YAML` file is valid and equivalent to the above images JSON response???

```
responses:
     '200':
         description: 'Request is successful.'
         schema:
           $ref: '#/definitions/Images'

definitions:
   Images:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Image'

   Image:
      type: object
      properties:
         name:
           type: string
         content:
           type: string
      required:
          - name
          - content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response schema is missing the wrapper property `images`. Other than that, your definition is correct.

Change your `Images` schema as follows:

```yaml
definitions:
   Images:
       type: object
       properties:
           images:
               type: array
               items:
                   $ref: '#/definitions/Image'
       required:
           - images
```